# /etc/environment and cron

Tags: fedora, centos, environment-variables, cron

I've got two machines: Fedora and CentOS. And a cronjob

```
0-59 * * * * env > /home/me/env.log
```

On CentOS I can see that /etc/environment is affecting the output while on Fedora it does not. I want Fedora to be like CentOS. What do I need to make it happen?

/etc/pam.d/crond on Fedora

```
auth      sufficient pam_rootok.so
auth       required   pam_env.so
auth       include    system-auth
account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    system-auth
```

/etc/pam.d/crond on CentOS

```
auth      sufficient  pam_env.so
auth       required   pam_rootok.so
auth       include    system-auth
account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    system-auth
```

/etc/security/pam_env.conf is the same on both systems and consists of commented out lines.
Even if I make /etc/pam.d/cron.d files the same, problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of `pam_env` to `session` -- `crond` skips authentication, because it can just use `setuid()`.

Also check whether `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` is the same.